# Calculate price by elapsed time php mssql server

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I have a parking system and I try to make a php script to calculate price than print to POS printer.

I get the insterted time  from mssql like :  2013-01-04 12:49:49

I would like to calculate   the elapset time to `timenow();`

than set value like this in minutes:

```
if 30 = 0;
if 60 = 1;
if 120 = 2,50
```

...... and and  :-)

is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this please using [`DATEDIFF`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp):

```
   SELECT CASE `X.ElapsedTime` 
               WHEN  MOD 30 = 0 THEN 0
               WHEN MOD 60 = 0 THEN 1 
               WHEN MOD 120 = 0 THEN 2 
               ELSE Null END AS `ElapsedCount` 
   FROM (SELECT  DATEDIFF(mi, startime, GetDate()) AS `ElapsedTime`
   FROM yourtable) X;
```

Another approach would be (if you require you may round it up):

```
   SELECT (`X.ElapsedTime`/60 + '.' + `X.ElapsedTime` MOD 60) as `ElapsedCount`
   FROM (SELECT  DATEDIFF(mi, startime, GetDate()) AS `ElapsedTime`
   FROM yourtable) X;
```

Or using `hh`:

```
   SELECT  DATEDIFF(hh, startime, GetDate()) AS `ElapsedCount`
   FROM yourtable;
```

---

### EDITING OP'S query in the comment to use JOINs

```
SELECT top 1 dbo.Partners.IdPartner AS pid, 
dbo.Partners.PartnerName AS name, dbo.Partners.MemberNumber AS nr, 
dbo.T_PAID_KARTE.MAGNETNA_COD, dbo.T_PAID_KARTE.ACTIVE AS active, 
dbo.T_PAID_KARTE.TYP AS cardnime, dbo.T_PAID_KARTE.ID_PAIDBY, 
dbo.T_LOGG.EXIT AS exittime, DATEDIFF(mi, exittime, GetDate()) AS ElapsedCount, 
dbo.T_LOGG.ID_PARTNER 
FROM dbo.Partners
INNER JOIN dbo.T_PAID_KARTE
ON 
INNER JOIN dbo.T_LOGG
ON 
;
```

Comment: will try now thx, first will select the last row from LOGGING than sort by id DESC LIMIT 1 .... so i get the inserted data, than i select again tha same ID from LOGGING like you write, than i schould get back the differet if i right understand :-)

Comment: So you want to get user's most recent log record for parking? Then yes you may `SELECT TOP 1 DATEDIFF(hh, startime, GetDate()) AS `ElapsedCount` FROM yourtable WHERE USERID = ? ORDER BY DESC`, if you have a particular use you can use the `ID` to filter out the record for that user. Else simply use without `WHERE` clause. And SQL Server use `Top 1`.

Comment: I have from 2 different DB all the stuff what i must print out, like name and last visit  and elapsed time from last visit cose we hawe a fitnes too. if the visitor was 30min bevor in fitnes than is the parking free. this is why i would like to calculate it by php and not select from sql or mssql. i get the row like this: Last Visit:   Feb 4 2013 02:58:54:790PM  and now  the one thing what to do is get the time now and calculate the different. than i get a summ  if summ >30 than price="1"euro if summ >60 price="2"

Comment: You may also sum up the all the elapsed time for a user. Do you have a separate table that holds pricing for hourly basis? So it can be joined with filtered records for parking to calculate the final sum to be paid. Apology I can only provide you an answer from SQL Server, since you have tagged it as SQL Server, if you need to use MSQL then please retagged it as MYSQL. In that case `DATE_DIFF(start,end)` would be the syntax to use, plus you may use `limit` instead of `top`.

Comment: ok i got it...SELECT top 1
    dbo.Partners.IdPartner AS pid,
    dbo.Partners.PartnerName AS name,
    dbo.Partners.MemberNumber AS nr,
    dbo.T_PAID_KARTE.MAGNETNA_COD,
    dbo.T_PAID_KARTE.ACTIVE AS active,
    dbo.T_PAID_KARTE.TYP AS cardnime,
    dbo.T_PAID_KARTE.ID_PAIDBY,
    dbo.T_LOGG.EXIT AS exittime,
    DATEDIFF(mi, exittime, GetDate()) AS ElapsedCount,
    dbo.T_LOGG.ID_PARTNER
   
    
FROM
    dbo.Partners, dbo.T_PAID_CART , dbo.T_LOGG   so i get in minutes the differet

Comment: now  just the php :-) `if($elapsed < 30){
    $summe="FREE":  
             }
     if($elapsed > 30){
        $summe="1":  
  }`  how can i make the BETWEEN summ and a simplest code?

Comment: Oliver see my edit to your query in the above comment. It's best to use `join` :) Can you tell me how these three tables are related to each other? The foreign key relationship?

Comment: yes, in one are data from customer, 2: paid parking and fitness card, in the last one is the logg file for IN nd OUT

Comment: **Can you tell me how these three tables are related to each other? The foreign key relationship?** The common fields in each table? e.g. Customer ID can be found in parking and fitness card perhaps?

Comment: `if($elapsed < 30  ){
    $summe="FREE":  
         }elseif{
      ($elapsed > 30  && $elapsed < 60 ){
             $summe="1":
         }elseif{
       ($elapsed > 60 && $elapsed < 90 ){
             $summe="2":
         }elseif{
       ($elapsed > 120 && $elapsed < 150 ){
             $summe="3":
   }`

Comment: As mentioned oliver I can only help you with SQL query but PHP. If you are not providing the relationship/related fields to join the three tables then also it's hard to complete that last query. So please help us to help you.

Comment: You soved my problem already :-) now i just make some php code. BIG THX!!!! hope i can help also ;-)

Comment: Glad you got it worked. :) Please use `joins` to make your sql query efficient. It's vital. If you had gotten any proper help from this answer to your question, you can accept it by clicking the tick next to voting arrows.

Comment: uff,,,, one more thing :-) a small one, i have in the mssql db slovenian characters like  š and č . I cant convert to utf8.. always get È or like this :-/

Comment: This could help you understand what should be done. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/155859/why-do-we-need-to-put-n-before-strings-in-microsoft-sql-server and `usage of N`. [Collation & unicode support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx)